# How to switch from VirtualBox to VMWare

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox, vmware-player

I've worked with virtual box (6.X and 7) on windows 10 for a few months and it was a pitty. From network-issues (Host-only vs. NAT vs. NAT-Network etc.) to lagging machines to .vdi-files that were removed/set in quarantine from Microsoft Defender (to name only a few issues).

I've made the decission to switch to VMWare Player. But how can I port a VirtualBox-VM to VMWare, including networks and hard disks? How to install guest additions? And what if the VM cannot be configured? Turns out: Not sooo easy...

Answer (score 0):

I've had a few issues and I didn't find a single resource, were everything was mentioned. Here is some kind of step-by-step guide for you:

### Create (importable) appliance

[This documentation](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2053864) was were I started. If you select File -> Export Appliance you have to **select the right Format** which is **Open virtualization Format 1.0**. Not 2.0 (why though?) or 0.9. You can decide which network-configuration you want to export and if you want to include your iso-images or not. I included the manifest-file, iso-images and all network configurations.

If you proceed, you can review your settings. Tip: If present, **uncheck DVD-drive with virtual-box guest additions**. You'll not need them anymore.

### Import appliance

In VMWare Player select "Open a virtual machine" and select your .ova-file. Now type in your VM-Name and storage path. **Tip:** Unlike virtual box, VMWare will not create a default directory for all VMs or a directory for the VM you're creating. Putting each VM you import into an own directory is a good idea.

**Import failed**? Don't worry, just click retry and everything should work. The above mentioned documentation says the same...

### Run! Run?

I've tried to start my Windows Server 2019 right away - **you shouldn't!** Instead try to "Edit virtual machine settings". If you encounter "VMWare Player unrecoverable error" [don't worry](https://superuser.com/questions/1753667/accessing-settings-of-an-imported-vm-using-vmware-throws-could-not-get-the-data). Open the newly created *.vmx file in a text editor and set `virtualHW.version = "20"` to `virtualHW.version = "19"`. Now you`re able to open the settings. Select the Options-Tab and check which "Guest operation system" is selected. In my case "other" was selected. Select the OS your'e machine is running.

If you want to [install VMWare tools](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1014294) (equivalent to virtual box guest additions) you have to attach a CD/DVD drive.

If everything is successfully imported and configured, your VM should be able to run. **Side channel mitigations enabled?** Well, [you should buy pro](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/79832) ;)

And don't worry about "Cannot connect the virtual device". Just enter "Yes" and everything should work as expected.

To avoid further problems you should uninstall VirtualBox GuestAdditions. Just type uninstall in start menu and you should find Uninstall Guest Additions from VirtualBox.

### Install VM Ware tools

Now your're able to install VM Ware tools. Select Player -> Manage -> Install VMWare Tools and everything should work out of the box. Good luck :)